# Find string in a list of strings, and then set the string to the found string?

Tags: c++, string, find

C++ programming assignment

So I'm have a list of strings

```
static const string mCodes[] = {
    "AAD - Architecture Design",
    "AAE - Architecture",
    "AAI - Interior Design",
    "AAL - Landscape Architecture",
    "AAP - Urban Planning",
    "AAS - Afro-American Studies",
    "ABS - Architecture Building Science",
    "ACA - Architecture Construction Mgmt",
    "ACC - Accounting",
    "AES - Aerospace Studies"};
```

I am having the user define studentMajor as a 2-4 character string using the student's major code (ie. studentMajor = ACC)

I need to search the list of strings, and if it finds ACC in that list of strings, it sets studentMajor to the full string that ACC was found in.

```
if( student variable is found ) then
    studentVariable = "ACC - Accounting"
else
    error, improper student major entered
```

I assume I need to be using std::find, but I'm unsure how to go about finding "ACC" in that list, and then taking the full string "ACC" is attached to and storing it into the variable.

I think its an easy manipulation of std::string::find and std::string::substr, but I'm not sure at all how to tackle this.

Thanks

Comment: `std::find` and `std::substr`? Do you mean `std::string::find` and `std::string::substr`?

Comment: @Blaze I do, my apologies

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `std::for_each` and just search for the supplied string in each full string. I'd also use a `std::vector` of `std::string` to store the strings. Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

const std::vector<std::string> mCodes = {
    "AAD - Architecture Design",
    "AAE - Architecture",
    "AAI - Interior Design",
    "AAL - Landscape Architecture",
    "AAP - Urban Planning",
    "AAS - Afro-American Studies",
    "ABS - Architecture Building Science",
    "ACA - Architecture Construction Mgmt",
    "ACC - Accounting",
    "AES - Aerospace Studies"};

std::vector<std::string> find_matches(const std::string& in) {
    std::vector<std::string> rv;

    // loop through all mCodes
    std::for_each(mCodes.begin(), mCodes.end(),
        // call lambda function for each mCode
        [&](const std::string& full) {
            // check if the "in" string can be found in "full"
            if(full.find(in)!=std::string::npos)
                // if so, save "full" to "rv"
                rv.push_back(full);;
        }
    );

    // return a vector of all found strings
    return rv;
}
```

An alternative if you want to use exact matching of the 2-4 letter codes could be to use a `std::unordered_map` where you make a map between the codes and the full name of the courses. Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

const std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> mCodes = {
    {"AAD", "Architecture Design"},
    {"AAE", "Architecture"},
    {"AAI", "Interior Design"},
    {"AAL", "Landscape Architecture"},
    {"AAP", "Urban Planning"},
    {"AAS", "Afro-American Studies"},
    {"ABS", "Architecture Building Science"},
    {"ACA", "Architecture Construction Mgmt"},
    {"ACC", "Accounting"},
    {"AES", "Aerospace Studies"}
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::vector<std::string> args(argv+1, argv+argc);

    for(auto& str : args) {
        auto it = mCodes.find(str);
        if(it != mCodes.end()) {
            std::cout << it->first << " - " << it->second << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by running it through a for loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 221; i++){
    if(mCodes[i].find(testMajor) == string::npos){
        testMajor = mCodes[i];
        return testMajor;
    }
}
```

Where 221 is the full size of the array mCodes. This just manually searches every single element of mCodes, and if a search comes back positive, set testMajor to that element of the array :)

Thanks y'all

Comment: Use `mCodes.size()` instead of `221`.

Comment: ... and also, your test should be `!= string::npos`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question lends itself to a map which uses the course code as the key into a map.  Here is a quick example.

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

static const std::string mCodes[] = {
    "AAD - Architecture Design",
    "AAE - Architecture",
    "AAI - Interior Design",
    "AAL - Landscape Architecture",
    "AAP - Urban Planning",
    "AAS - Afro-American Studies",
    "ABS - Architecture Building Science",
    "ACA - Architecture Construction Mgmt",
    "ACC - Accounting",
    "AES - Aerospace Studies"};

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::string> course_map;

    for(auto const& course: mCodes) {
        std::string code = course.substr(0, course.find(" "));
        course_map.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string>(code, course));
    }

    if(course_map.find("ACC") != course_map.end() ) {
        std::cout << "course is " << course_map["ACC"] << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "ACC not found." << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```